# WP-CLI cron on multisite using WP-Toolkit "succeded", but callback not executed

Tags: multisite, wp-cron, wp-cli

I'm trying to trigger WordPress crons within a multisite using Plesks WordPress toolkit.

Generally it is working, but the callback doesn't seemed to be executed.

The **command** to execute crons:

```
 /sbin/plesk ext wp-toolkit --wp-cli -instance-id 2 -- cron event run --due-now --url=example.com
```

The **result of the command**:

```
Executed the cron event 'my_callback' in 0.003s. Success: Executed a total of 1 cron event.
```

**Problem**

Nothing happens. The jobs is not executed. No logs, no change, nothing.

**Notes**

- The job **is** working with "classic" cron via HTTP call

Any advice is much appreciated.

Thank you.